# Plotting UK regions using GADM data in R

Tags: r, polygon

I want to produce a map of the UK, and be able to colour code regions by colour. The regions I have in my dataset include North East, South East, West Midlands, Wales, Norther Ireland etc

I have been using the gadm dataset, but this doesn't seem to have this data. It is either not enough detail and by country, or is too granular. Is there any other dataset which I could download which will have the regions? At the moment I have only got as far as producing the map

```
library(sp) 

gadm <- readRDS("C:/Users/User/Documents/R_input/gadm36_GBR_2_sp.rds")
plot(gadm)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the regions you are looking for can be found under the "Regions" category of "Administrative Boundaries" at the Office for National Statistics. They only contain boundaries within England, so the different UK country outlines must be downloaded separately and the two sets joined together. Fortunately the ONS has a GeoJSON API.

Here's a full reprex:

```r
eng <- rgdal::readOGR(paste0("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/",
                              "8d3a9e6e7bd445e2bdcc26cdf007eac7_4.geojson"))

countries <- rgdal::readOGR(paste0("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/",
                                   "92ebeaf3caa8458ea467ec164baeefa4_0.geojson"))

eng <- sf::st_as_sf(eng)
countries <- sf::st_as_sf(countries)
UK <- countries[-1,] 
names(eng)[3] <- "Region"
names(UK)[3] <- "Region"
UK$objectid <- 10:12
eng <- eng[-2]
UK <- UK[c(1, 3, 9:11)]
UK <- rbind(eng, UK)

ggplot2::ggplot(UK, ggplot2::aes(fill = Region)) + ggplot2::geom_sf()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The details of GADM datasets depend on the level of details requested. Try the the function `getData` from `raster` package.

```
library(raster)
# gadm <- <- getData('GADM', country='GBR', level=2) # the one you have
gadm <- getData('GADM', country='GBR', level=3) # more detailed than yours
plot(gadm)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the previous solution didn't work for me, I came up with an easier alternative using the **{sf}** package.

You can download the *GeoJSON* for all of the 12 regions (NUTS Level 1) here: [www.geoportal.statistics.gov.uk](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/e9cfbf2e478a481bb367eb2f2891d504_0/explore?location=55.030204%2C-3.316605%2C6.00)

I'm also simplifying the shapes for faster plotting.

```
uk <- sf::st_read("NUTS_Level_1_(January_2018)_Full_Clipped_Boundaries_in_the_United_Kingdom.geojson") %>%
      sf::st_simplify(preserveTopology = TRUE, dTolerance = 1000) 

uk %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = nuts118nm)) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image: ggplot2 Map UK]